# Recommended Wireless Mini Keyboard with Trackball

Tags: keyboards, trackball

I want a keyboard to use with my gaming/htpc.

I will use it from the sofa so a wireless, mini keyboard would be best.
I feel game controller sticks a comfortable device, therefore I want a trackball (that I think feel closer to a stick) in the keyboard, rather than a trackpad. I will not use the trackball for gaming, I play games with a controller.
Finally it would be great if the keyboard came with a kind of charging dock (so that I can just grab it and use it), but this last requirement is not a priority.

Can you think of any models that fit those conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used a compact IOGEAR keyboard on an HTPC before. I was impressed with how comfortable it felt to hold.

Product: [IOGEAR Multimedia Keyboard (Model: GKM561R)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002H0BOBA)

[image: IOGEAR Keyboard]

This keyboard has the following features:

- Rubber grips on the sides
- Separate scroll wheel and track ball
- Mouse sensitivity adjustments
- Compact

It does not have a charger though. It utilizes two AA batteries.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I opted for a different model, because it seems to have better support for Japanese language (which I also needed). However, for more general cases I think @Andy's answer is the best choice.

I bought this Japanese Bluetooth wireless trackball keyboard: [Miyoshi's TK-BT01](http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B00GM5VMPY)
[image]